# Returning data from a phonegap build android plugin

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am making my first phonegap build plugin, but I have been unable to return data from the java to the javascript.

At this point I have done all of the setup work I think I would need to do, but have been able to return anything to callbacks.

The java includes what I think is the required includes

```
package com.power_6.baseball_native_card_calculation;

import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class CardCalculation extends CordovaPlugin {

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        if (action.equals("getCardBatter")) {
            callbackContext.success("it works");
        } else {
            callbackContext.error("it failed");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

My Javascript or this is:

```
if (window.cordova) {
var exec = require("cordova/exec");

var getCardCalculation = {
    getCardBatter: function (successCallback, failureCallback) {
        exec(
            successCallback,
            failureCallback,
            "CardCalculation", "getCardBatter", []);
        console.log('batter ran')
    },
    getCardPitcher: function (successCallback, failureCallback) {
        exec(
            successCallback,
            failureCallback,
            "CardCalculation", "getCardPitcher", []);

        console.log('pitcher ran');
    }
}

module.exports = getCardCalculation;

function cardCalculateSuccessCall (){
    console.log('Works');
    //console.log(response);
}

function cardCalculateErrorCall (){
    console.log('Failed');
    //console.log(response);
}
}
```

Whenever I call this from inside of the PhoneGap Build Debug window, I'm not getting any response from the callbacks.

I'm not sure what else to include, but thank everyone for any help you can provide.

The GitHub for this is: https://github.com/cdearcangelis/baseball-native-card-calculation
The Phonegap Build Plugin is: https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/2327

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
getCardCalculation.getCardBatter(function(result){alert(result);},function(error){alert(error);});
```